# SQL create table from a select distinct with conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I have a table, lets call it table1 which has many columns, of this table I want to now create a new table which contains unique values of one column of table1 grouped or with unique values of another column if in a third column teh value is equal to "staff"

```
column1 | column2 | column3 | ....
  john  |   store |  staff  
  luis  |   front |  staff
  carlos|   store |  temp 
  luis  |   front |  staff
```

what I want would be a table like this:

```
 user | dept 
 john | store
 luis | front
 john | front
```

my first attempt:

```
create table users
as 
   select distinct column1,column2
   from table1
   where column3 ='staff'
```

this however is not a correct syntax , it says "incorrect syntax near the keyword select.

so my second attempt was this :
create table
as

```
   Select Distinct column1, from table1 group by column2 where column3 = 'staff'
```

However this attempt gives me thee same error. My SQL syntax knowledge is not that good as you can see so I wanted to know first if it was possible to do something like this, and second what would be the correct syntax. This is so I can create a index table that I can use instead of having to create this in power bi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a table based on your `SELECT` statement.

```
select distinct column1, column2
into table2
from table1
where column3 ='staff'
```

This statement above will create a new table with the name **table2** based on the columns in `SELECT` and their data types. In this case **table2** will have two columns with names **column1** and **column2**.

Answer (score 1):

Emin has the way to do it if you want the table schema conferred from the select query, which is likely what you desire. See his answer if that is your desire, as that is the correct statement to create and insert.

If you want to select into a table you create, create the table and then you can do an INSERT INTO with a SELECT DISTINCT statement as your query. This would be more like:

```
INSERT INTO NewTableName (Column1, Column2) 
SELECT DISTINCT Column1, Column2
FROM TableNameHere
WHERE Condition = "something"
```

As mentioned, you will have to create the table first with this method, but you can explicitly control the columns in the table (noting that a change in type will require a CAST or CONVERT to the new type in your SELECT).